# Does designing an automatic interaction based on user intent a good thing?

Tags: interaction-design

We have this flow in our interface where user can unlink their accounts that are connected to the application. We have a button to unlink their bank, but we also have an option where user can manually unlink each account. The process here is quite tricky because they need to click the “submit” button once they are okay with their changes,  reason being they need to enter 2FA,and we do not want them to enter 2FA for each change or unlink that they do for each account if needed. Sorry for the bad sketch but this is how it is currently laid out:
[image]

In cases that user tries to manually unlink each account and does not use the “unlink bank” option, the suggested interaction is when user clicks the last account with the “Unlink”, the system will detect their intent to unlink all accounts and the bank and will show a confirmation dialog if they want to unlink the bank:
[image]

It is a good interaction as it detects the intent of the user and it removes one step which is clicking the “update” button, however my concern is that clicking on the last “unlink” button and then showing a confirmation dialog after might be something unexpected? I’m not sure if the modal interrupts the user work flow since it is detecting that it wants to unlink all accounts which equals to unlinking the bank and one less click of clicking the update button, while the modal offers a second chance whether to cancel or not. Is there an article that would suggest this is a bad idea?

We cannot do user testing at the moment that is why this is challenging. But I’d like to get your thoughts or if you have any articles you could share that relates to this topic, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Is is permitted (by your business logic) for a user to unlink all accounts but still keep the bank linked?

Comment: The modal interrupts the flow and is not really needed. Why do users unlink all accounts one by one while they actually wanted to unlink the bank? My suggestion is to make it directly available like the other unlink options.

Comment: @jazZRo: I think it is directly available too. I think the question is about when a user selects all accounts which is equivalent of the "unlink bank" option. So OP is asking if it should just automatically do that same as if the user click "unlink bank".

Comment: Yes I thought that too, but if it is more prominently available as part of all other unlink options, the suggestion is already given. No modal needed. Another idea is to make it appear under the last account as soon as the last account gets unlinked, but why not show it always?

Comment: @musefan it won’t keep the bank linked if they unlink all accounts, and then the modal will say that this will equal to unlinking the bank.

Comment: @jazZRo yes that option is available too but this is for instances when users just tries to manually unlink it one by one. thanks for the comments.  I think the team wanted to hide the unlink bank option and just show option to each linked account in case they want to unlink some of them. but that’s a good point to. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would take a step back and try to find out “what % of people unlink all accounts in one go vs people unlink 1 or more” and solve for maximum frequency.

The general solution can be giving them ability to select one or multiple accounts using check boxes and 2 ctas  -

() Account 1
() Account 2
() Account 3

**Unlink Selected**
This only gets active when accounts are selected

**Unlink All**

I would also add an alert prompt if this action can’t be undone once performed.

Comment: good point. currently we don’t have any data yet as this is something new, but will bring that up to the team next time. Maybe we can just decide what’s best for now and once we have data, that’s when we can make changes. Thanks for the suggestions.